# can compilation libraries work without python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, exe

I try to make python editor with compiler to exe, which can work on PC where Python isn´t installed.

Is possible to run these libraries (PyInstaller,cx_Freeze,py2exe) on PC where isn´t Python, or it´s impossible